# Python - how to reset the order of number in the column data frame name pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

here is my data frame

```
Student_Id St_Name
1          John
2          Mark
3          Zen
4          David
5          Max
6          Sanny
7          Seolla
```

and I have removed sum number in this data frame

```
Student_Id St_Name
2          Mark
4          David
5          Max
7          Seolla
```

but i would like to re-order it. and the expectation of this output will be

```
Student_Id St_Name
    1          Mark
    2          David
    3          Max
    4          Seolla
```

I have tried df.Student_Id.reset_index(). but, it's not working.

Comment: Have you considered creating a new DataFrame and filling it with the column 'St_Name'?

Comment: it is mean, i have to insert more column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Student_Id'] = df.reset_index().index + 1
df

Student_Id  St_Name
1   Mark
2   David
3   Max
4   Seolla
```

**OR**

```
df['Student_Id'] = range(1, df.shape[0]+1)
```

Comment: i see, after reset_index(), must continue with index+1... thank you for your comment!